# Conditionally modifying text in multiple identically named children

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to conditionally modify the content of some XML.  Am element has multiple identically named children, which I want to modify based on the text content.  For example, I have the below XML:

```
<first>
  <second>
    <third>alice</third>
    <third>bob</third>
    <third>charlie</third>
  </second>
</first>
```

Which I'd like to transform  into:

```
<first>
  <second>
    <third>xavier</third>
    <third>yvonne</third>
    <third>charlie</third>
  </second>
</first>
```

I had thought the below xsl would work, but it doesn't (I suspect for a couple of reasons).  What am I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/first/second/third/">
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="contains(text(), 'alice')">
       <xsl:text>xavier</xsl:text>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="contains(text(), 'bob')">
       <xsl:text>Yvonne</xsl:text>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
   </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things you're doing wrong:

- You have a slash at the end of this XPath `/first/second/third/`. Syntactically, it's not legal to have a slash at the end of an XPath, and you don't need one here.
- You have a template that's supposed to match `third` elements (basically providing a substitute for what they once were), but you're not copying the elements. You're just replacing them with text, which means you'd have a result like:

```
<first>
  <second>xavieryvonnecharlie</second>
</first>
```

In order to get your attempt to work, modifying the template to this should be sufficient:

```
<xsl:template match="/first/second/third">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains(text(), 'alice')">
        <xsl:text>xavier</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="contains(text(), 'bob')">
        <xsl:text>Yvonne</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

However can do this much more cleanly by having templates to match the text nodes you want to replace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="third/text()[. = 'alice']">xavier</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="third/text()[. = 'bob']">yvonne</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<first>
   <second>
      <third>xavier</third>
      <third>yvonne</third>
      <third>charlie</third>
   </second>
</first>
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks.  Seems so easy when you put it like that, and bonus points for elegant alternative.